# Matrix API not routing correctly

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api, google-distancematrix-api

We have had an increase in bad zip codes the last few days.  This happens occasionaly, but it's genearlly a route from an island or something.  Key West to Kentucky as an example.  However, now it's mapping a lot of zips to France.

11040 (Geo result: New Hyde Park, NY 11040, USA) to 08810 (Geo result: Dayton, NJ 08810, USA)

https://google.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=11040&destinations=08810&key=my_key

RESULT:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Dayton, NJ 08810, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "11200 Bizanet, France" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

64161 (Geo result: Kansas City, MO 64161, USA) to 30033 (Geo result: Decatur, GA 30033, USA)

https://google.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=64161&destinations=30033&key=my_key

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Decatur, GA 30033, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "64520 Came, France" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

It's mapping the zip codes to odd locations.  The geolocation API finds them and correctly pulls in the address based on the zip code, just the distancematrix call is having issue with the zip codes.  I only have the zip available.  Why is everything pointing to France today?

Comment: Are all the zip codes US codes?  Perhaps add the country to the requests. [example](https://google.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=64161,%20USA&destinations=30033,%20USA)

Comment: yes all are valid zips.  country works sometimes but not always

Comment: Please provide an example where the country doesn't work. Are you sure they are all valid US zip codes that are associated with a location?

Comment: The country doesn't work because I don't have the ability to add the country.  I only have the zip available to me.  This app is international so can't hardcode the country.  Yes they are all valid zip codes as you can see from the examples above.  This has been working for over a year - just stopped functioning last Friday morning.  We process tens of thousands of these a day with a very low error rate.

Answer (score 0):

We're encountering the same thing for a high-volume app. Not able to recognize destinations with only a 5-digit postal, and mistaking some 5-digit postal origins as locations in France.

A quick workaround is to append "USA" to the end of any 5-digit postal code (ie. "12345 USA"), append "Canada" to any postal code containing letters, and append "Australia" to any 4-digit postal code.

We're only working with locations in these 3 countries so adjust accordingly.

Comment: That's going my solution as well I think. Unfortunately it requires a code release so in testing at the moment.  Was hoping there was something easier with a setting in the API or something.  We're finding a lot of them missing too.  12345 doesn't return a result, 12345,USA does.